# Is there a way to use proxies with scrapy without using middleware?

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

From searching how to use proxies with scrapy I mostly found solutions that requires me to use some sort of middleware. Is there a way to just have the spider.py file handle the proxy itself when its doing requests? For example, in the Python requests library you can add a proxy argument when creating a request, is there something similar like that when using scrapy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using middleware? No, that's the point of middleware! However scrapy has inbuilt middlewares for that and you don't need to download or enable anything.
You can set proxy for any individual Request via `proxy` key in `meta` attribute:

```
Request('someurl', meta={'proxy': 'http://some_proxy_server:port'})
```

Checkout [HttpProxyMiddleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=proxy#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy)

Comment: yea I figured that this was the case, I think my best solution is to use Requests and BeautifulSoup to not deal with the entire framework with scrapy since I only need a one time thing with limited functionality

Comment: @EdwardFu Scrapy is perfectly capable working in small scale. There's nothing wrong with middlewares. Requests has the same logic as HttpProxyMiddleware it's just not isolated and exposed like the middlewares - it's hardcoded in.